# Making android github project available via gradle

Tags: android, github, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have created a library project using android studio and uploaded it on Github

What I want to do is, make the project available to anyone wanting to use it with this simple gradle command.

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.myprojectname'
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

To use a project in github with gradle:

- publish it in MavenCentral or Jcenter
- use [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/)

In this case add the repo:

```
repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

and add the dependency like this:

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
    }
```

If you want to publish an artifact on MavenCentral, you can read [this post](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAAahUKEwi9kvHz2qjIAhVE7xQKHf1bBUE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgmariotti.blogspot.com%2F2013%2F09%2Fpublish-aar-file-to-maven-central-with.html&usg=AFQjCNEtnFgnWlqhFwITTbQaHc7zmQO7Lg&sig2=_HBKg_s5VGXXyTd2nj0vvg&bvm=bv.104317490,d.bGg).

Comment: any tutorial on publishing to jcenter? I'm going through jitpack in the meantime

Answer (score 1):

You should upload your project on maven central or jcenter or on your own repository somewhere on the internet.

Then in the gradle.build your users specify:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

or similar and then they specify your dependency

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.myprojectname+'
}
```

Comment: could you provide a link for a tutorial for uploading to jcenter?

Comment: I don't know how to upload to Maven, never did. Should be straightforward, I think. You may want to find the info on Maven Central itself.

Comment: I guess best would be to  publish to jcenter as the default build.gradle now has the jcenter repository added by default. (They changed it from mavenCentral() some time before)